# Excluding spark from uber jar with maven

Tags: maven, apache-spark

How can I just compile my spark code to put onto remote server without also packaging spark which I have defined in maven? I don't need any of the spark dependency since I obviously already have it installed on the server when I run spark-submit. Still pretty new to maven. So far I'm thinking of possibly using shade plugin but not sure if that's the right way to go. Just trying to refine a workflow where I test my spark apps locally and then just need to package a jar for running on a remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use scope `provided` in your dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```